# List output being duplicated

Tags: python, list, output

I created a simple recursive function that determines whether a number is even or odd, performs math on them, and appends them to a list:

```
iter_list = []
def function(n):
    iter_list.append(n)
    if n < 2:
        print iter_list
        print iterations
        pass
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        even = n / 2
        iter_list.append(even)
        collatz(even)
    elif n % 2 == 1:
        odd = (3 * n) + 1
        iter_list.append(odd)
        collatz(odd)
    else:
        print "Code not working."
        pass

stdin = input("Number")
print collatz(stdin)
iterations = len(iter_list) - 1
```

When I run the function with 276, the output is:

```
Number[276, 138, 138, 69, 69, 208, 208, 104, 104, 52, 52, 26, 26, 13, 13, 40, 40, 20, 20, 10, 10, 5, 5, 16, 16, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Which is what I would expect, except that there are two instances of each number, instead of one.
How would I fix this?

Comment: I imagine you meant `def collatz(n):`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at what happens when `n == 4`:

```
def function(n):
    iter_list.append(n)
    if n < 2:
        print iter_list
        print iterations
        pass
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        even = n / 2
        iter_list.append(even)
        collatz(even)
    ...
```

1. On line 2, we append `4`.
2. On line 9, we append `2`.
3. We call `collatz(2)`
4. On line 2, we append `2`.
5. On line 9, we append `1`.
6. We call `collatz(1)`

Note that we added `2` twice! Perhaps you should only append to the list at the beginning of your function instead of additionally inside the conditionals.